# DateTime handling in AngularJS and WebAPI

Tags: angularjs, datetime, asp.net-web-api

I am working on a **new** application which already having data. The dates in database are stored in local timezone. I set webAPI formatters as DateTimeZoneHandling.Local.

The issue is, users can be in different time-zones. when they receive the dates, there are in the server's timezone.

On the client, whatever changes they do in dates, the Angular transformers change the dates to UTC before sending that to server. This time, server changes that back to it's local time and saves back to the database.

This time, the date stored is not what user's actually selected but the local date of the server and is causing inconsistency in the data.

I want this conversion to preserve the datetime at both the ends. Any suggestion?

Comment: DataTime in database should be always UTC time

Comment: The problem is, i received the database from the customer and they have been storing in local time zone in their previous application.

Comment: That's core problem, convert to UTC if you can

Comment: Yes that is the last option, there are a lot of ssrs reports being generated and i have to make all those changes to convert the dates when generating the reports

Comment: That's a huge problem. Dates should always be stored in UTC. The client (browser) who is responsible (and only accurately capable) of converting it to the user's time zone.